# App.config modifications revert after exit

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, config, app-config, configurationmanager

I am modifying my MyApp.vhost.exe, and the App.vhost.exe is modified as I can see in the text editor, but when I stop the debug application, the App.config values revert back to what they were before the change. What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

```
Configuration exeConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
var section = exeConfiguration.GetSection(monitorSectionElementName);

if (section != null)
{
    var monitorPathElements = (section as MonitorSection).MonitorPaths;
    monitorPathElements[monitorPath].CheckSum = checkSum;
}

exeConfiguration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(monitorSectionElementName);
```

Comment: Do they revert back when you run the application (F5 or CTRL+F5) from visual studio?

Comment: Are you editing the config while debugging the code? It feels like the debugger is 'reverting any changes it made' at the wrong time.

Comment: Editing config through the configuration manager does not edit your app.config file.  That (app.config) is a source file that gets copied to your runtime folder at build time.

Comment: Please refer to my updated change to the post.